# Instring Function in R

Tags: string, r

Close to finishing up my first project entirely in R, but I am stuck.  I don't really have a good grasp of regex, but usually can accomplish my tasks with substring, instring, len, or comparable functions.

I have two questions.  Where can I find a list of string functions in R, and  2nd, does R have an instring type function?

Many thanks in advance!

Brock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like working with the [`stringr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html), which gives a consistent interface to the R string functions. It has functions like `str_detect()` and `str_locate()` which may address your instring needs.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Text_Processing) reference anwswers both questions.

HTH!

Comment: So you should check rseek.org

Comment: @mbq Thanks! I tried it a few times in the past, but got lots of unrelated links. May be I should try again.

Answer (score 1):

This might point you in the right direction:

```
help.search(keyword = "character", package = "base")
```